# How to Get the java.util.function input parameters in exception block

Tags: java

How to Get the input arguments/parameters of java.util.function in exception block

In the below code, I want to get the input parameters that are supplied to the function. When processWithRetry(..) throws ApplicationException or any other exception and we do retry 10 attempts to do retry. When the retry fails for 10 times then we need to which Employee object has failed in Exception block

When i debug and check function parameter has mulipleArgyments args1, arg2, arg3, in runtime. One of the raguments points to Employee Object. How to get function arguments in below exception block.

When i say function.applyThen(..) method is there but no function.getParameters() or getArgs().. methods available.

```
catch (ApplicationException e) {
    if (i == nRetries - 1) {
        throw e;
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {             
    e.printStackTrace();    
    Long failed = 0L;
    result = (T) failed;                
}
```

Below is the complete code and flow.

```
Public class EmployeeProcessor {

    public void processEmployee() {

        BlockingQueue<Optional<Employee>> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100000);
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                try (for every DB connection from pool) {
                    while (true) {
                        Optional<Employee> take = queue.take();
                        if (!take.isPresent()) {
                            break;
                        } else {
                            Employee employee = take.get();
                            long count = processWithRetry(connectionObject, 10, dbSession -> {                          
                                // many statements here, but no try & catch block, but processing might throw ApplicationException      
                                return 0L;
                            });
                        }
                    }       
                });
                threads[i].start();
            }
        }   

        for (String filePath : fileList) {          
            processFileByFile(filePath, queue, connectionObject);

        }
    }

    protected void processFileByFile(String filePath, BlockingQueue<Optional<Employee>> queue, DBconnectionObject)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        try {
            String dataLine;    

            while ((dataLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                if (dataLine != null && dataLine != "") {                   
                    List<String> eachLineList = Arrays.asList(eachLine.split(","));
                    queue.put(Optional.of(
                            new Employee(eachLineList.get(0), eachLineList.get(1), eachLineList.get(2))));
                }

            }           
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }


    class Employee {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String age;

        public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    <T> T processWithRetry(connectionObject connectionObject, int nRetries, Function<dbSession, T> function)
            throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException, ApplicationException, UnsupportedOperationException {
        if (nRetries < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of attempts: " + nRetries);
        }

        T result = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < nRetries; i++) {
            try {
                result = function.apply(connectionObject);
                break;
            } catch (ApplicationException e) {
                if (i == nRetries - 1) {
                    throw e;
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {             
                e.printStackTrace();

                Long failed = 0L;
                result = (T) failed;                
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Get one of the arguments what i see in inpsect during debug time. in the Below exception block.

```
catch (ApplicationException e) {
                if (i == nRetries - 1) {
                    throw e;
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {             
                e.printStackTrace();

                Long failed = 0L;
                result = (T) failed;                
            }
```

Comment: Isn't `connectionObject` is what you looking for?

Comment: Hi @talex, Not connectionObject. When i debug in eclipse, see function has below arguments...  ```function = <some random number>
 arg$1=com.employee.service.EmployeeProcessor$$Lambda$25/619640257@330f389f
 arg$2=com.employee.service.EmployeeProcessor@3c5e1d51
 arg$3=com.employee.service.EmployeeProcessor$Employee@d58e3e
``` Want to fetch the 3rd argument which has failed during the processing.

Comment: So you want to get `employee` returned by `take.get()` in `processEmployee` inside `processWithRetry`?

Comment: @talex, Yes .. as the function object holds the Employee object as one argument in runtime. When it exceptions, the return type result (T) will also null. Syntactically not possible. Any API's which i am not aware of to use to get the 3rd param??.

Comment: No luck. You can use reflection, but solution will be very unstable, because generated field name may be changed at any moment.